# What is the purpose of List settings -> version settings -> Require content approval for submitted items?

Tags: content-approval

We are using SharePoint 2013. I would like to know what is the purpose of 'Require content approval for submitted items?' with an example of how it can help to achieve a purpose. Take any example.

Answer (score 2):

Versioning can be useful in many scenarios like collaboration. Take a simple example of expense management system. A user goes in and adds the details of his expenses (travel, food etc). At this time the expenses will be in pending state. The manager of the user can then approve/reject his claims. So, it will turn into either approved/rejected. Another example can be of many users working on documents in a library. There may be a selected group of people who will approve/reject their changes.

Moreover if **Item Version History** is enabled then changes to a particular document/item can be tracked. The big advantage with versioning is that one can go back to previous version as well.